# Firebase Crashlytics not reporting crashes when manually enabled

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

Crashlytics works just fine without opt-in reporting. But it stops reporting anything as soon as I set up opt-in reporting according to the [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/customize-crash-reports?authuser=0).

Specifically, I added the following content to `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<meta-data
    android:name="firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled"
    android:value="false" />
```

And I added the following into the `onCreate`:

```
 Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
```

With a debugger, I am sure that the above line has been executed.

However, nothing is reported to the Crashlytics. Instead, the logger gives the following,

```
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
D/Fabric: Generating Crashlytics ApiKey from google_app_id in Strings
D/Fabric: Using AdvertisingInfo from Preference Store
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
D/Fabric: Build ID is: ...
D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics is disabled, because data collection is disabled by Firebase.
D/Fabric: Initializing io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric [Version: 1.4.6.29], with the following kits:
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics [Version: 2.9.7.29]
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta [Version: 1.2.10.27]
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers [Version: 1.4.5.29]
    com.crashlytics.sdk.android.crashlytics-core [Version: 2.6.6.29]
D/Fabric: Not fetching settings, because data collection is disabled by Firebase.
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Manifest
D/Fabric: Falling back to Crashlytics key lookup from Strings
D/Fabric: Build ID is: ...
D/Fabric: Analytics collection disabled, because data collection is disabled by Firebase.
D/Fabric: Could not get parcel from Google Play Service to capture AdvertisingId
D/Fabric: Could not get parcel from Google Play Service to capture Advertising limitAdTracking
D/Fabric: AdvertisingInfo not present
D/Fabric: Asychronously getting Advertising Info and storing it to preferences
```

I have noticed this interesting line: `D/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics is disabled, because data collection is disabled by Firebase.` which is probably the cause of the issue. Yet I can't find any information about this log.

Comment: I am experiencing exactly the same problem, and it seems that is is a bug in version 2.9.7. With that version if Crashlytics is disabled in manifest it is not possible to enable it programmatically. Using 2.9.6 the same code works perfectly.

Comment: @gicci Downgrading to 2.9.6 made it work! You should write this as an answer and I will accept it :) Thank you!

Comment: reason maybe that you need to migrate from fabric

Comment: Make sure for meta tags first then upgrade, in my case the code was too old and meta tag was false.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is an issue with Firebase Crashlytics 2.9.7 preventing opt-in reporting as described in the documentation to work: the start of Crashlytics from code will not be performed.
For the time being downgrading to 2.9.6 will enable your code to work properly.

Comment: Man this drove me crazy

Comment: It was the same for me until I saw this question here. Anyway the bug was confirmed also by Firebase support which I contacted.

Comment: is this solved in 2.10.1? As I am still facing the issue

Comment: I face same with 2.10.1. Downgrading to 2.9.6 fixes the issue. Could it be that the bug only appears in more recent created firebase projects? We have an old project that works with 2.10.1 but our new project only works with 2.9.6

Answer (score 2):

Please follow this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59906454/6743289

For those wish to use crashlytics for their android app who haven't been using crashlytics of fiber.io, there are certain changes in the way you FirebaseApp is initialized which you will find in the above link.

Answer (score 1):

Use following dependencies for android.
Paste it into *build.gradle* app:

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
transitive = true
}
```

Upgrade it from 2.9.5 to 2.9.6.
It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line into Application class

```
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply but I have already added this into the `onCreate` of my activities and I can confirm that this line is executed, as I have mentioned in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Crashlytics 2.9.8 has been released which fixes the bug. I've tested to confirm. The [changelog](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/update):

> 2.9.8 December 21, 2018
>
> - Fixed bug with firebase_crashlytics_collection_enabled flag that erroneously disabled data collection under some circumstances.

Comment: Facing the issue in 2.10.1 . I am testing using this line 'Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();'

Comment: @DKV yes it worked after some delay. I was facing difficulty in multi module app.

Comment: @Ravi Yadav: for me debug build working  perfectly.  But not the release

Comment: @DKV invited you to chat

Answer (score 0):

Initialization of app is not mentioned anywhere to get crashlytics report on our console!

**Step 1**. First follow the official doc's link to include all dependencies as it is given there and setup your firebase app through firebase console.

**Step 2**. Now do the following initialization in your base application class or base activity class.

**FirebaseApp.initializeApp(getApplicationContext());
FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true);**
Now clean you project and do some force crash for few times, you should be able to see your crashlytics report on your firebase console

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I followed [Test Your Crashlytics implementation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/test-implementation?platform=android#enable-debug-logging) to debug the issue.

Setting `FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().setCrashlyticsCollectionEnabled(true)` fixed the issue, even though I expected it to be doing that by default

Answer (score 0):

If you are done add dependency and other steps still not working means you can **turn on your internet** then try to crash it will be report into the firebase dashboard.